# Connected to internet but router shows that I am not connected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My computer is wired to the router and I can access the internet but the router shows that I am offline (orange light)
all other computers that are connected via wifi or wired are showing up as green
what is going on? Not a big deal as I can connect to the internet but I want to understand the situation

Comment: " the router shows that I am offline" forget the light, inside the DHCP service is there IP for your PC? and it's shows as active!

Comment: orange vs green light on a wired connection is often a sign it connected at 100 Base-T rather than 1000. Check your cables.

Answer (score 1):

Check the speed / duplex configured on your ethernet interface, and if it's possible set it to *autonegotiate*.

Your ethernet port will adapt to the speed and duplex capabilities offered by the router and it's very likely the connection be signaled by green instead of orange.